# Which LEGO set bricks with words Basel, Genova, Hamburg, Post belong to?

Tags: set-identification, vintage

I have these bricks with these words on them. I have searched on the internet, but can't find what sets these would go to.
Does anyone know ?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Those pieces were in one set: [113-2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=113-2) from 1966.

[image: 113-2]